# How to generate 6 months average spend prior current date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.3. and I haven't had much exposure with running totals

I have a requirement where I am required to generate a report per year with the average six month spend of a customers prior or after their first order in a given year.

Below is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  persistent_key_str character varying,
  ord_id character varying(50),
  ord_submitted_date date,
  item_sku_id character varying(50),
  item_extended_actual_price_amt numeric(18,2)
);





INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('01120736182','ORD6266073','2010-12-08','100856-01',39.90);
INSERT INTO orders   VALUES('01120736182','ORD33997609','2011-11-23','100265-01',49.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD33997609','2011-11-23','200020-01',29.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD33997609','2011-11-23','100817-01',44.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD89267964','2012-12-05','200251-01',79.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD89267964','2012-12-05','200269-01',59.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01011679971','ORD89332495','2012-12-05','200102-01',169.99);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD89267964','2012-12-05','100907-01',89.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD89267964','2012-12-05','200840-01',129.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD125155068','2013-07-27','201443-01',199.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01120736182','ORD167230815','2014-06-05','200141-01',59.99);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES('01011679971','ORD174927624','2014-08-16','201395-01',89.99);
```

This is I have:

```
    WITH year_cte
as
(
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ord_submitted_date) ord_year, ord_id, ord_submitted_date from ORDERS
)

SELECT  --persistent_key_str
     c.ord_year  
    --, ord_id 
    , AVG(AVG(o.item_extended_actual_price_amt)) OVER(PARTITION BY c.ord_year) Avg_6_month_spend
FROM orders  o INNER JOIN year_cte c ON c.ord_id = o.ord_id
WHERE o.ord_submitted_date between (c.ord_submitted_date - interval '365 days')::date and  c.ord_submitted_date 
group by o.ord_submitted_date, o.item_extended_actual_price_amt, c.ord_year
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle with the above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3e570/1).

I would really appreciate for some guidance in the task.

---

I expect to see something like this. 
"Ord_year","Avg 6 Month Spend"

```
2010, 1645.39, 
2011, 255.94, 
2012, 247.53, 
2013, 230.36, 
2014, 239.82,
```

Comment: What is the mark for the customers? It seems that dates can go in a next or previous year?

Comment: @MladenUzelac, it could be either.

Comment: You have an extra avg in avg(avg(...)). The result is the same. To get ranking in windowing function use rank() function (if you want to get first date in a year). It's difficult to the query from your data because you have data with a year interval between orders. So to get a 6 month before and after is impossible.

Comment: Could you give an example of expected results for data provided in the question ?

Comment: @MladenUzelac                                                             i just made up these numbers but I expect to see something like this.                                                "Ord_year","Avg 6 Month Spend"
2010,1645.39,
2011,255.94,
2012,247.53,
2013,230.36,
2014,239.82,

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT q.year, avg( o.item_extended_actual_price_amt )  
FROM (
   SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ord_submitted_date) as year,
          min( ord_submitted_date ) as first_order_date
   FROM ORDERS
   GROUP BY year
) q
JOIN ORDERS o
ON o.ord_submitted_date 
   BETWEEN q.first_order_date - INTERVAL '6 months'
       AND q.first_order_date + INTERVAL '6 months'
GROUP BY q.year
ORDER BY q.year
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3e570/29

Comment: Looking at this Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5897e/4, I am getting the same values for both Average 1 year spend and Average 6 months spend which might not be right. How do I correct this? Any ideas!

Comment: Explaining further, the CTE in the demo  generates the first time orders of a customer which I exclude in the join when calculating the the Average Six months spend.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, I had this question here and I am linking it to [stackoverflow] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158135/how-to-get-the-discount-number-of-customers-in-prior-period?answertab=votes#tab-top