# How to get the discount number of customers in prior period?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a requirement where I supposed to roll customer data in the prior period of 365 days.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders     ( 
  persistent_key_str character varying, 
  ord_id character varying(50), 
  ord_submitted_date date, 
  item_sku_id character varying(50), 
  item_extended_actual_price_amt numeric(18,2) 
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO orders VALUES
('01120736182','ORD6266073'  ,'2010-12-08','100856-01',39.90), 
('01120736182','ORD33997609' ,'2011-11-23','100265-01',49.99), 
('01120736182','ORD33997609' ,'2011-11-23','200020-01',29.99), 
('01120736182','ORD33997609' ,'2011-11-23','100817-01',44.99), 
('01120736182','ORD89267964' ,'2012-12-05','200251-01',79.99), 
('01120736182','ORD89267964' ,'2012-12-05','200269-01',59.99), 
('01011679971','ORD89332495' ,'2012-12-05','200102-01',169.99), 
('01120736182','ORD89267964' ,'2012-12-05','100907-01',89.99), 
('01120736182','ORD89267964' ,'2012-12-05','200840-01',129.99), 
('01120736182','ORD125155068','2013-07-27','201443-01',199.99), 
('01120736182','ORD167230815','2014-06-05','200141-01',59.99), 
('01011679971','ORD174927624','2014-08-16','201395-01',89.99), 
('01000217334','ORD92524479' ,'2012-12-20','200021-01',29.99), 
('01000217334','ORD95698491' ,'2013-01-08','200021-01',19.99), 
('01000217334','ORD90683621' ,'2012-12-12','200021-01',29.990), 
('01000217334','ORD92524479' ,'2012-12-20','200560-01',29.99), 
('01000217334','ORD145035525','2013-12-09','200972-01',49.99), 
('01000217334','ORD145035525','2013-12-09','100436-01',39.99), 
('01000217334','ORD90683374' ,'2012-12-12','200284-01',39.99), 
('01000217334','ORD139437285','2013-11-07','201794-01',134.99), 
('01000827006','W02238550001','2010-06-11','HL 101077',349.000), 
('01000827006','W01738200001','2009-12-10','EL 100310 BLK',119.96), 
('01000954259','P00444170001','2009-12-03','PC 100455 BRN',389.99), 
('01002319116','W02242430001','2010-06-12','TR 100966',35.99), 
('01002319116','W02242430002','2010-06-12','EL 100985',99.99), 
('01002319116','P00532470001','2010-05-04','HO 100482',49.99);
```

Using the query below I am trying to get the number of distinct customers by order_submitted_date:

```
select
    g.order_date as "Ordered",
    count(distinct o.persistent_key_str) as "customers"
from
    generate_series(
        (select min(ord_submitted_date) from orders),
        (select max(ord_submitted_date) from orders),
        '1 day'
    ) g (order_date) 
left join
    orders o on o.ord_submitted_date between g.order_date - interval '364 days'
                                         and g.order_date
WHERE extract(year from ord_submitted_date) <= 2009
group by 1
order by 1
```

This is the output I expected.

```
Ordered      Customers
2009-12-03   1
2009-12-10   1
```

When I execute the query above I get incorrect results.
How can I make this right?

Comment: Please learn to format your posts

Comment: Unrleated but: please don't compare apples to oranges. `extract(year...)` returns a number, but `'2009'` is a string value. Numbers don't need single quotes

Comment: @juergend I am really struggling on how to format my code whenever I come here, What is the best way to do good code formatting?

Comment: The way it is formatted now.

Comment: What do you mean by `I am trying to the number of distinct customers` ? Could you explain in a few words how the desired output is calculated ? It's hard to guess looking only on input data, an incorrect query and a desired output.

Comment: Your query string hints that you'd want 1 row for every day in the result, while your "expected output" only displays days with actual rows. Which is it?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, this was just a basic beginning but I am expected to roll up the number of distinct customers by year. So joining the orders table to the dates table by using the ord_submitted_date, I would get the calendar year.

Answer (score 0):

To get your expected output ("the number of distinct customers") - only days with actual orders 2009:

```
SELECT ord_submitted_date, count(DISTINCT persistent_key_str) AS customers
FROM   orders
WHERE  ord_submitted_date >= '2009-1-1'
AND    ord_submitted_date <  '2010-1-1'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Formulate the `WHERE` conditions this way to make the query [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), and input easy.

If you want *one row per day* (from the earliest entry up to the latest in `orders`) - within 2009:

```
SELECT ord_submitted_date AS ordered
     , count(DISTINCT o.persistent_key_str) AS customers
FROM  (SELECT generate_series(min(ord_submitted_date)  -- single query ...
                            , max(ord_submitted_date)  -- ... to get min / max
                            , '1d')::date FROM orders) g (ord_submitted_date) 
LEFT   join orders o USING (ord_submitted_date)
WHERE  ord_submitted_date >= '2009-1-1'
AND    ord_submitted_date <  '2010-1-1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f57fe/1)

#### Distinct customers per year

```
SELECT extract(year from ord_submitted_date) AS year
     , count(DISTINCT persistent_key_str) AS customers
FROM   orders
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f57fe/4)

Comment: it does meet my expectations. I rolled up the number of distinct of distinct customers by year. Thank you

Comment: @user7922: Distinct customers per year is simpler, yet.

Comment: @ErwinBranstetter How do you calculate the average 6 months spend of a customer in a  prior period using the schema above? This needs the exclusion of the first time orders of a customer. Is it possible to paste my code here?